# Allow HTML input in Joomla Contact input fields

Tags: joomla, filter

By default, Joomla seems to strip and remove any HTML content entered into the Contact details.

I want to add line breaks to the address textarea box. Now, I understand I need to add `filter="raw"` to the XML file, which would mean hacking the core. (from this article: http://docs.joomla.org/Textarea_form_field_type)

Is there anyway to do this via an override instead?

Comment: Please delete your duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea :

1. Make an overide of this file : "components\com_contact\views\contact\tmpl\default_address.php"
2. Replace `<?php echo $this->contact->address .'<br/>'; ?>` by `<?php echo str_ireplace('-br-' ,'<br />', $this->contact->address) .'<br/>'; ?>`

When you provide an adress, write "-br-" for each break line.

Comment: You did miss out the closing bracket, but very interesting! let me try this!

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks for that. I should have thought of that! I was only thinking of the admin form side of things